# Android: populate listview in a fragment from volley callback

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I cannot print my listview, received from a Volley callback.

This is my `ListCampaignFragment.java` :

```
public class ListCampaignFragment extends ListFragment {

    private BaseApp app;
    private View v;
    private ListView list_campaign_view;
    private List<ModelCampaign> campaignList = new ArrayList<ModelCampaign>();
    private CustomListCampaignAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_campaign_fragment, container, false);

        //registerForContextMenu(this.listView);

        app = (BaseApp) getActivity();
        getCampaign();

        adapter = new CustomListCampaignAdapter(app, campaignList);

        list_campaign_view = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list_campaign_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    private void getCampaign() {

        String token = app.token_debug;

        ApiMapper mapper = new ApiMapper();
        //mapper.getCampaign(token);

        mapper.getCampaign(new ApiMapper.VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONArray campaigns) {

                for (int i = 0; i < campaigns.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = campaigns.getJSONObject(i);
                        ModelCampaign campaign = new ModelCampaign();

                        Log.d("TEST", obj.getString("name"));
                        campaign.setNameCampaign(obj.getString("name"));
                        campaign.setTypeCampaign(obj.getString("type"));
                        campaign.setIdCampaign(obj.getInt("id"));

                        // adding campaign to campaigns array
                        campaignList.add(campaign);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }, token);


    }

}

Log.d("TEST", obj.getString("name"));  prints the right name, so callback is executed and code received the JSON object without problem.
```

This is the `CustomListCampaignAdapter.java`

```
public class CustomListCampaignAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ModelCampaign> campaignItems;

    public CustomListCampaignAdapter(Activity activity, List<ModelCampaign> campaignItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.campaignItems = campaignItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return campaignItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return campaignItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getIdCampaign(int position){
        ModelCampaign m = campaignItems.get(position);
        int idCampaign = m.getIdCampaign();
        return idCampaign;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_campaign_row, null);

        TextView nameCampaign = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campaign_name);
        TextView typeCampaign = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campaign_type);

        // getting movie data for the row
        ModelCampaign m = campaignItems.get(position);


        // nameCampaign
        nameCampaign.setText(m.getNameCampaign());
        typeCampaign.setText(m.getFormattedTypeCampaign());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And finally this is the layout `list_campaign_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the `list_campaign_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_list_row" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/campaign_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My code compile and executes without errors, but I cannot see anything on the simulator (I would have a list of 6/7 items in my scenario, demostrated from the Log).

Thank you for your help

### EDIT

I added a Log.d in the method View of the CustomListCampaignAdapter, but I cannot see nothing in the log.

[...]

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_campaign_row, null);

        TextView nameCampaign = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campaign_name);

        TextView typeCampaign = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campaign_type);

        // getting movie data for the row
        ModelCampaign m = campaignItems.get(position);


        // nameCampaign
        nameCampaign.setText(m.getNameCampaign());
        typeCampaign.setText(m.getFormattedTypeCampaign());

        Log.d("CLCA", m.getFormattedTypeCampaign());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add results to the list you need to inform the adapter of the changes. Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I added the notifyDataSetChanged() but it doesn't work. In effect I pass the array directly on the constructor, I don't make an add or similar...

Comment: Where did you add it? It doesn't matter if you give the list to the adapter's constructor. At that point the list is empty. It's not until after you get the comet response that you are adding a model object to the list. It's after this add you need to notify the adapter of the change to the data.

Comment: This is code edited with your suggest, but it doesn't work... Thank you for your patience: adapter = new CustomListCampaignAdapter(app, campaignList);

        list_campaign_view = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list_campaign_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Basically, I added it between list_campaign_view.setAdapter(adapter); and return v;

Comment: Nope, not the right place. You need to call notify in the `onSuccess` method, right after adding the new model object to the list.